# Changing the subject of an equation where desired subject appears twice

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble rearranging the following equation to solve for $a$

$r = \frac{m-a}{m+a}$

I got as far as multiplying both sides by denominator and expanding brackets on left to give:

$rm + ra = m - a$

but now I'm stuck with how to get past the rearranged:

$ra + a = m - rm$

I must be missing something but I can't see how to get rid of the $r$ on the left hand side.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: $a(r+1)= m-rm$.  Divide by (r+1), provided $r\neq -1$: $a= \frac{m(1-r)}{r+1}$.

Comment: thanks for pointing out I am going to run into issues with r = -1 as I mentioned on another comment below -1 would be a valid input for the system I am describing so I may have to abandon this approach altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a good start, and all we need to do here is factorise the LHS:

$$
ra+a=m-rm \\
\implies a(r+1)=m-rm \\
\implies a = \frac{m-rm}{r+1}
$$

At this point, we have made $a$ the subject. Personally, I would also factorise the RHS:

$$
a = \frac{m(1-r)}{r+1}
$$

But you don't really need to do this—it all depends on the context. One of these expressions is not simpler than the other.

(Sidenote: as User amWhy has pointed out, this only works if $r+1 \neq 0$. If $r+1=0$, then $a$ could take any value.)

Comment: hi, thanks, and to amWhy for pointing that out. I might need to have a think about what I'm using this for as in my application r = -1 would be perfectly valid input but I've also run into division by zero issues on all the other ways of doing it I've tried. That this ended up in the same place with more steps (thanks everyone) means I'm back to the drawing board.

Comment: There are my appreciations.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that  the LHS is just $a(1+r)$, so you can divide both sides by $1+r$ to get $$a=\frac{m-rm}{1+r}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

$$r=\frac{m-a}{m+a}=1-\frac{2a}{m+a}=1-\frac2{\dfrac ma+1}.$$ Now $a$ only appears at one place.

> $$\frac ma+1=\frac2{1-r},\\a=\frac m{\dfrac2{1-r}-1}=m\frac{1-r}{1+r}.$$

Comment: I don't think this a suitable approach because it is more complicated than it needs to be. There are more direct ways to make $a$ the subject that do not require this kind of elaborate rearrangement.

Comment: @Joe: I did expect such a comment, but not a downvote. My goal was to show an alternative solution that works by removing an occurrence of the subject. I do agree that it yields a more complicated solution in this case.

Comment: OK I will not downvote this answer because I agree that the ideas you used in this answer are applicable in other contexts (even if in this context a more direct approach would be easier).